# Overload method with generic method and parameter

Tags: java, generics, methods, overloading

I've been looking through countless pages trying to figure out if it is possible to overload a method with a `List` parameter, with another method that has the generic return parameter `List<E>`. I understand that this should always try to be avoided, but it's for an assignment, and I would like to keep both methods included if it is actually possible. Below is the code for the two methods:

```
// This method returns an array of the info.
Object[] toArray(List data) {
    Object[] array = new Object[data.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = data.get(i);
    }

    return array;
}

// Overloaded version that uses Generics.
E[] toArray(List<E> data) {
    return toArray(data);
}
```

My question is, besides changing the name, is there any way to differentiate the parameters that would allow both methods to be in place, and that would not cause a `name clash` error? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Note: someone asked the question "[How to overload a method with generic parameter in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535206/how-to-overload-a-method-with-generic-parameter-in-java)" on StackOverflow, which was close to what I needed, but not quite.

Comment: You can't do it the way you have suggested, you have to change something. At runtime the generic name is dropped so in fact you have two methods with the same signature which is why it will never work. I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201231/java-erasure-with-generic-overloading-not-overriding

Comment: There was a way in Java 6, but this was due to a bug in the compiler which has been fixed. In short, no you can't do this.

Comment: You can also get a hint from the compiler's error message. What does it tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to overload the method because Java does this implicitly for you with raw types.

```
<E> E[] toArray(List<E> data) {
```

If you call

```
List objs = ...
Object[] array = toArray(objs);
```

and if you use generics you get generics

```
List<String> strs =
String[] array = toArray(objs);
```

The real problem you have is there is no way to implement toArray.  This is because the generic type is not known at at runtime. i.e. you can't create an array of `E` nor can you cast an `Object[]` to a `String[]` for example.

What you can do is pass the type of the array to use.

```
public static Object[] toArray(List list) {
    return toArray(list, Object.class);
}
public static <E> E[] toArray(List<? extends E> list, Class<E> eClass) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    E[] array = (E[]) Array.newInstance(eClass, list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: +1. I want to bring up a fine point. JLS 15.12.2 states that when overloading a method where one takes the argument `C` and the other a supertype or subtype of `C`, the method chosen for a type higher in the hierarchy is the more specific method. However, according to JLS 4.2.10 `List` is a supertype of `List<E>`, so one might think that such overloading is possible where `List<E>` is the more specific one. Fine points about generics reveal that this is not the case.