# Check generic type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, wildcard

I have two methods ListPrint and ListPrint2. The Difference between them is generic type  of the list "List_1". How do I make a method that depending on type T type will do different things?

ListPrint_3 achieves pretty much what I want but I would like instanceof to reffer to type  rather than single object inside the list.

Thank you for your help.

```
static  void ListPrint(ArrayList<Integer> List_1){
    System.out.println(List_1.get(0).toString());
}

static  void ListPrint_2(ArrayList<String> List_1){
    System.out.println(List_1.get(0));
}

static <T> void ListPrint_3(ArrayList<T> List_1){

    for (Object e : List_1) {
        if (e instanceof Integer){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        if (e instanceof String){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(List_1.get(0));
}
```

Comment: "How do I make a method that depending on type T type will do different things?" - you can't. Erasure won't let you.

Comment: Followup to question asked by @rgettman: You can call `toString()` on a String. It will just return itself. So you code can just unconditionally call `e.toString()` without any `instanceof` checks. Unless rgettman was right and you're trying something different than what is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java erasure with generic overloading (not overriding)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201231/java-erasure-with-generic-overloading-not-overriding)

Comment: toString() is just example. I'm more interested if I can do polymorphism (or something of sort) with Lists as parameters.

I want to achieve something like this (and compiler to accept it):
`code`
static  void ListPrint(ArrayList<Integer> List_1){
    System.out.println(List_1.get(0).toString());
}

static  void ListPrint(ArrayList<String> List_1){
    System.out.println(List_1.get(0));
}
`code`

If it's impossible then I'm fine. Just curious if it's possible.